# Should I report my S-corp dividends on my 1040 as sched-C self-employment or 1099-div?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, s-corporation, schedule-c, form-1099-div

I'm using TurboTax and am confused how to report my profits from my S-corp.

On my S-corp K-1, I set line 17c "Div distributions paid from accum earnings" equal to my S-corp's ordinary business income.

But should I enter this as 1040 sched-C income or just 1099-DIV?

More Details:
I'm a self-employed consultant.  I entered all my earnings in the 1120S including all expenses.
I filled out the K-1 as follows: 
Line 1:  all my income from 1120s line 21 = $105000
Line 17c =$105000
Line 18 = $105000

Comment: Line 17 code C is not where any kind of distributions would appear on a S-Corp K-1 so I guess I'm a little confused by your question.  Could you possibly add a few details?

Comment: Then I'm confused.  How do I indicate, on the 1120S, the amount of earnings that I flowed through to my personal 1040 form?  Should I erase line 17c and assume IRS will know the about on line 18 flows through to my 1040?

Comment: The sentence starting "On my S-Corp K-1," is where the confusion is.  What you really mean is Line 17c from Schedule K of your 1120S.  That is where your share of earnings would show up on the corporate return, not on the K-1.  The number on the K-1 from Line 17c of Schedule K would show up in Box 1 as you have noted in your edited version.

Comment: Just to clarify my previous statement, there is no line 17c on a K-1.  You can put a number on line 17, but if you use code c it will be translated as "Qualified Rehabilitation Expenditures" which I don't think is what you want.  You are probably thinking of line 17c from Schedule K of your Form 1120S and that would not be correct either under the facts you have given so far.